# Inserting code into a page just shows raw HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to insert a youtube playlist into a page using the following code

`<iframe width="853" heigh![t="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=<ID-REMOVED>&amp;hl=en_US" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe][1]>`

for some reason, even when the ID is there, it comes out like this

Sorry about the text, it's by the client.
Never really worked with wordpress before. I don't see a place to insert code or anything.
Wat do?

Comment: well, the picture didn't post, here's an imgur link

http://i.imgur.com/WLW7vkd.png

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question, the WordPress automatic paragraph input is messing up the raw html

[Placing google maps into a wordpress page using the wordpress page editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139788/placing-google-maps-into-a-wordpress-page-using-the-wordpress-page-editor)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to embed a youTube video you can just paste the link directly in the editor.  For example, pasting http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ in the editor will automatically embed the video on the page.

Here is [more info on embeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds).

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the HTML as visual whereas you should input under the Text field[image]